# Sencha Touch ExtJS adding checkbox to list

Tags: javascript, mobile, extjs, sencha-touch

Doing development in Sencha Touch 1.0.
I'm using Ext.List to render a list, but I also want the start of each list item to start with a checkbox. I also want to change its state based on an array item value, the array which is given to  config option. Is there a way to add a simple Ext.form.Checkbox to an Ext.List.

If I instead use a `<input type="checkbox".../>` to the `<itemTpl>` config option, then it looks ugly in display and secondly I don't know how to listen to events on the checkbox

Here is the code for ur eye candy:

```
Ext.regModel('Todos', {
    fields: ['title', 'completed_at']
});

var groupingBase = {
    itemTpl: '<div class="contact2"><strong>{title}</strong></div>',
    selModel: {
        mode: 'SINGLE',
        allowDeselect: true
    },
    // grouped: true,
    indexBar: true,

    onItemDisclosure: {
        scope: 'test',
        handler: function (record, btn, index) {
            alert('Disclose more info for ' + record.get('title'));
        }
    },

    store: new Ext.data.Store({
        model: 'Todos',
        sorters: 'title',

        getGroupString: function (record) {
            return record.get('title')[0];
        },

        data: [todos] //todos array is prev populated with required items' properties 
    })
};

myList = new Ext.List(Ext.apply(groupingBase, {
    fullscreen: true
}));
//List ends

tasksFormBase = {
    title: 'Tasks',
    iconCls: 'favorites',
    cls: 'card2',
    badgeText: '4',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [
    myList, {
        xtype: 'checkboxfield',
        name: 'cool',
        label: 'Cool'
    }],
    dockedItems: [todosNavigationBar]
};
```

//tasksFormBase is then added to a Ext.TabPanel  config option

any help form Ext master???

Answer (score 5):

I figured out, I need to use a template
I used the itemTpl property of the List control with the tpl looking like:

```
<textarea id="todos-template" class="x-hidden-display">
            <div id="todo_item_{todo_id}" class="todo_list">
                <input type="checkbox" id="todo_check_{todo_id}" class="todo_checkbox unchecked"/>         <strong>{title}</strong>
            </div>
</textarea>
```

and added the following listener:

```
itemtap: function(dataview, index, item, event) {
var todo = dataview.getStore().getAt(index).data;
if (eve.getTarget('input#todo_check_'+todo.todo_id)) {
                    Ext.get(item).addCls('selected');
                    ele = Ext.get('todo_check_'+todo.todo_id);

                    //reverse condition as the event is fired before the state is set
                    if(!ele.getAttribute('checked')) {
                        todo.completed_at = Api.formatDate(new Date());
                        ele.replaceCls('unchecked', 'checked');
                    } else {
                        ele.replaceCls('checked', 'unchecked');
                        todo.completed_at = null;
                    }
}
```

So on tapping the list item, I detect whether the checkbox is tapped and change the relevant div CSS classes accordingly. I hope the same thing can work for radio as well.

Comment: hey buddy can you provide me ur whole code in sencha touch 2.0 as i am stuck at the same problem in sencha touch 2.0.It will be very helpful if you do so and i'll be highly appreciate it.Thanx in advance.

Comment: It would be nice if you share it in GitHub, trying to achieve the same in a DataView with Touch 2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

For Sencha Touch the icons are stored in a font: Pictos. Here is the character [map](http://pictos.cc/font/)
For instance this is how I created a checkbox button(Note: the callback function is missing for the link). Simply change the font color to indicate checked or not.

In Css:

```
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
.icon {
 font-family: "Pictos"; 
}
```

In HTML:

```
<span>
  Item #1 
  <a href="#">
  <span class="icon">3</span>
  </a>
 </span>
```